# DateTime formatting Rails

Tags: ruby, datetime, date

I have "Date.today + 2.days" I need to format it using .strftime, but with the "+2.days" it doesn't recognize that method.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem, worked fine for me.

```
(Date.today + 2.days).strftime
#=> "2010-07-18"
```

Comment: thanks I did something dumb and forgot to put parentheses around

Answer (score 3):

Those nice helpers don't come with a vanilla ruby install. You need the `activesupport` gem (part of Ruby on Rails).

```
$ gem install activesupport

$ irb
ruby-1.8.7-p249 > require 'rubygems'
 => true 
ruby-1.8.7-p249 > require 'active_support'
 => true 
ruby-1.8.7-p249 > Date.today
 => Fri, 16 Jul 2010 
ruby-1.8.7-p249 > Date.today + 2.days
 => Sun, 18 Jul 2010
```